# Android Intent subclassing

Tags: android

I am using intents as a messaging mechanism of communication between various parts of my Android app.

My question is : can I subclass the Intent to build my own classes on top of it, or it will be the standard Intent class when I get it in the Broadcast reciever?

I am talking about intra process communication of course. But cross thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never done this myself, but I imagine that it's possible. Check out the `LabeledIntent` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LabeledIntent.html) and [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/content/pm/LabeledIntent.java) - I think this is similar to what you're describing. When handling your custom `Intent` in your receiver, you'll need to cast the `Intent` parameter in `onReceive()` to your own subclass.

If you add any fields to your subclass, you'll need to make sure to properly implement the `Parcelable` methods - make sure you override `writeToParcel()`, have a constructor that accepts exactly on `Parcel` parameter, and have a `public static final Parcelable.Creator` object.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. You can't cast an Intent to an Intent subclass.